# Adding a control to to the footer of gridview (asp.net) next to the paging stuff

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So is that possible?
I know you can add a footer template for specific column, but can you add a control int the footer next to the paging ?

Comment: What are your efforts?

Comment: Similar to if not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826235/add-control-to-right-of-previous-next-of-pager-in-asp-net-gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to check in the `Row_Created` event for a row of type `Pager`, like this:

```
private void grdClientServiceType_RowCreated(object sender,   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
       // Create your control here, button is an example create whatever you want
       Button theButton = new Button();
       theButton.Text = "Click Me";

       // Add new control to the row with the pager via a table cell
       e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan -= 1;
       TableCell td = new TableCell();
       td.Controls.Add(theButton);
       e.Row.Cells.Add(td);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 6 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell'  it would not let me add the button

Comment: Sorry about that, had a brain fart, grid views renders as tables by default and I had to add a table cell and then add the button to that to insert into the row's cell. Answer updated.